# For which real $s$ does $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$ converge?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For which values of real $s$ does the following converge?

$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}
$$

I have read extensively that the answer is $s>1$ but I can't find a simple proof suitable for students not trained to university level mathematics

Comment: The standard proof is by comparison to the corresponding integral. You can also give a pretty elementary proof using Cauchy condensation, which requires no knowledge of calculus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Comment: @TariqRashid Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $s>1$. For $k=2,3,\dots$, one has $2^k-1=3,7,15,\dots$ and

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^{2^k-1}\frac{1}{n^s} & = 1 +
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{2^s}+ \frac{1}{3^s}\Big) +  
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{4^s}+ \frac{1}{5^s} + \frac{1}{6^s}+ \frac{1}{7^s}\Big) +  
  %%
  %%
 \cdots + \Big(\frac{1}{(2^{k-1})^s}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(2^{k}-1)^s}\Big) \\  
  %%
   & < 1 +
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{2^s}+ \frac{1}{2^s}\Big) +  
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{4^s}+ \frac{1}{4^s} + \frac{1}{4^s}+ \frac{1}{4^s}\Big) +  
  %%
  %%
 \cdots + \Big(\frac{1}{(2^{k-1})^s}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(2^{k-1})^s}\Big) \\  
  %%
   & = 1 + \frac{2}{2^s} +\frac{4}{4^s}+  
  %%
 \cdots + \frac{2^{k-1}}{{2^{k-1}}^s}   
  %%
    = 1 + 2^{1-s}+ \big(2^{1-s}\big)^2 +  
  %%
 \cdots +  \big(2^{1-s}\big)^{k-1} \\  
  %%
   &  = \frac{1 - \big(2^{1-s}\big)^{k}}{ 1-2^{1-s}}
  %%
 < \frac{1}{ 1-2^{1-s}}<\infty. \\  
  %%
  %%
\end{align*}

Fix $s\leq 1$. For $k=2,3,\dots$, one has $2^k=4,8,16,\dots$ and

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=1}^{2^k}\frac{1}{n^s} & = 1 + \frac12+
 \Big(\frac{1}{3^s}+ \frac{1}{4^s}\Big) +  
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{5^s}+ \frac{1}{6^s} + \frac{1}{7^s}+ \frac{1}{8^s}\Big) +  
  %%
  %%
 \cdots + \Big(\frac{1}{(2^{k-1}+1)^s}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(2^{k})^s}\Big) \\  
  %%
   & > 1 + \frac12+
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{4^s}+ \frac{1}{4^s}\Big) +  
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{8^s}+ \frac{1}{8^s} + \frac{1}{8^s}+ \frac{1}{8^s}\Big) +  
  %%
  %%
 \cdots + \Big(\frac{1}{(2^{k})^s}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{(2^{k})^s}\Big) \\  
  %%
   & \geq 1 + \frac12+
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{4}+ \frac{1}{4}\Big) +  
  %%
 \Big(\frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{8}+ \frac{1}{8}\Big) +  
  %%
  %%
 \cdots + \Big(\frac{1}{2^{k}}+ \cdots + \frac{1}{2^{k}}\Big) \\  
  %%
   & = 1 + \frac12 +\frac12 + \cdots + \frac12  
  %%
 = 1 + \frac{k}{2} \rightarrow \infty
  %%
\end{align*}

Comment: This is the Cauchy condensation argument I mentioned in the comments: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way forward that relies only on the [Generalized Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) and
straightforward arithmetic.

For $s>1$, clearly we have

$$\begin{align}
n^{1-s}&=\sum_{k=1}^n \left(k^{1-s}-(k-1)^{1-s}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k^{1-s} \left(1-\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{1-s}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

Now, the Generalized Binomial Theorem reveals $\left(1-\frac1k\right)^{1-s}=1-\frac{1-s}{k}+O\left(\frac1{k^2}\right)$ so that

$$n^{1-s}=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1-s}{k^s}+O\left(\frac1{k^{s+1}}\right)\tag1$$

Rearranging $(1)$ yields

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^s}=\frac{1}{(1-s)n^{s-1}}+\sum_{k=1}^n O\left(\frac1{k^{s+1}}\right)\tag2$$

As $n\to \infty$, the first term on the right-hand side of $(2)$ goes to zero while the second term is a convergent series since $s+1>2$.  Therefore, the series on the left-hand side of $(1)$ must converge.  And we are done.

Comment: Is this not a circular argument? You say the second term in the right-hand-side  of (2) converges because $s+1>2$, but that's precisely the type of thing we're trying to prove here.

Comment: @Stefan: for exponents $\ge 2$ an elementary argument is possible by comparison to the telescoping series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(k+1)}$. The "hard" case is for exponents $<2$.

Comment: Might be worth adding this to your answer. Students might not know that.

Comment: @stefan Yes.  Some students might not have seen the telescoping series "trick" to estimate the for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^2}$.  And now Qiaochu's comment serves as the supplemental component to the posted solution. ;-)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: @TariqRashid Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)